# How can I bulk rename files taking into account some weights?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, rename, file-management

**I have hundreds of image files under this names :**

2008 singapore mclaren hamilton

1988_senna_mclaren_italy

senna 1985_portugal_lotus

schumacher_1998_great_britain ferrari

**and I want to rename them. For example I want them to look like:**

2008 - Singapore - Mclaren - Hamilton

1988 - Italy - Mclaren - Senna

1985 - Portugal - Lotus - Senna

1998 - Great Britain - Ferrari - Schumacher

**01)** The general view should be:

## YEAR - #CIRCUIT - #TEAM - #DRIVER

**02)** All words should start with Capital letter

**03)** Between the words I want the " - " (space, hayfen, space).

**04)** If there are duplicates, I want the photos to be renamed with a (#number) in the end. If there are 10 photos it is going to be like that:

YEAR - CIRCUIT - TEAM - DRIVER

YEAR - CIRCUIT - TEAM - DRIVER (2)

YEAR - CIRCUIT - TEAM - DRIVER (3)

...

YEAR - CIRCUIT - TEAM - DRIVER (10)

***I do not want to overwrite any existing photos !***

---

To achieve that I need to use some ifs in order to check if there is a four digit number in the string. Then this should go in the beginning of the new string. Afterwards, the " - " should be added. Then, the algorithm should check if there is a country name (circuit) in the original string. I should use an if for that where there will be 20-30 country names. HIGHLIGHT: Countries with 2 names will make my life difficult (eg Great Britain). Maybe I can check if there is any word like "Great" in the original string instead. After the circuit name addition, the same procedure goes for the "team" name and the "driver".

My main question is which is the best way to do this. As a first step, I will rename the files by just replacing the "_" with a " ". Secondly, I would all the words to start with a capital letter. Then, I can add the ifs to complete my task. Can I do it using the command line or should I make a batch file? I can also use a tool for that, but I will need to change the way it works by putting the specific ifs I need. Thank you for your time.

Comment: whatever way you choose: work on a copy of your files and keep the originals, until the task is finished.

Comment: @Stephan Exactly. I do not want to overwrite any files. I will first test it for some copies.

Comment: just wanted to mention it. Most people tend to do testing on their original data. :)

Comment: This is a lot of string compare with dictionaries (look up tables). It can be done in batch, but it's boring ;)

Comment: @Endoro I want to learn how to do it though. Then I can use this file for a lifetime. I have manually renamed 82,000 high res (large dimensions) pictures of Formula 1 even from the 1950s. I keep on saving new pictures so I want to find an automation.

Comment: What do you mean with `duplicates`? You can not have duplicates if your description is correct.

Comment: he can have `1988_senna_mclaren_italy`, `senna_1988_mclaren_italy`,`Italy_McLaren senna 1988` and so on - which all would result in the same destination name (= "duplicates")

Comment: @Endoro For example, I have more than 2 Schumacher photos from the 1998 Great Britain race. I want to keep both. That's what I mean duplicates (as far as concerned the name only. Not the file itself).

Comment: @Stephan is right ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might try this

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "CIRCUITS=Portugal\Singapore\Portugal\Great Britain\Bahrein\Italy"
set "TEAMS=Ferrari\McLaren\Lotus\Red Bull"
set "DRIVERS=Senna\Hamilton\Schumacher"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/a-d/on *.png *.jpg') do (
    call:GetYear "%%~a" year
    if not defined year exit /b
    call:GetString "%%~a" "%CIRCUITS%" circ
    if not defined circ exit /b
    call:GetString "%%~a" "%TEAMS%" team
    if not defined team exit /b
    call:GetString "%%~a" "%Drivers%" driver
    if not defined driver exit /b
    call:DoRename "%%~a" "!year! - !circ! - !team! - !driver!"
)
goto:eof

:GetYear
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "FName=%~1"
for /l %%b in (1940,1,2015) do (
    if not "!FName:%%~b=!"=="%FName%" (
        endlocal&set "%~2=%%~b"
        exit /b
    )
)
echo Year not found in "%~1" &exit /b

:GetString
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "Str=%~1"
set "Str=%Str:_= %"
set "Dict=%~2"
:next_1
for /f "delims=\" %%b in ("%Dict%") do (
    if not "!Str:%%~b=!"=="%Str%" (
        endlocal&set "%~3=%%~b"
        exit /b
    )
    set "Dict=!Dict:*%%~b=!"
)
if defined Dict goto:next_1
echo "%~1" has no match in "%~2" &exit /b

:DoRename
setlocal
set /a counter=1
:next_2
if %counter% gtr 1 (set "NewName=%~2 (%counter%)") else set "NewName=%~2"
set /a counter+=1
if /i not "%~1"=="%NewName%%~x1" if exist "%NewName%%~x1" goto:next_2
if not "%~1"=="%NewName%%~x1" (
    echo "%~1" --^> "%NewName%%~x1"
    ren "%~1" "%NewName%%~x1"
)
exit /b
```

Comment: This one works fine. Although I did not check if it works for the underscores too. If I click the batch file, it adds the (1) to every image even if there is no other file under this name. I want the numbering to start from (2).

Comment: @ApoloRadomer now better sorting & renaming, renaming counter starts with (2)

Comment: Ok. I have no problem if it starts from (1) then. If I execute the batch file once, it is done. If I re-execute it, then the filename (containing the (1) ) converts from "XXXX (1)" to "XXXX".

Comment: Cool. Sei grande @endoro :) Does it work for subfolders as well? In that case it is going to be more difficult. Because, it will have to check for the "duplicates" within the folders. In the past, I wanted to make a batch file that would sort all the files into the right folders. The file "1998 Great Britain" would go into the folder "1998" and then into the subfolder "06 - Great Britain". In the future I will make a post for that.

Comment: try to correct the "dir /b/a-d/o-n". "o-n" should be "on". Cheers !

Comment: I added better support for the capitalization: `"1985 - Portugal - Lotus - senna.jpg" --> "1985 - Portugal - Lotus - Senna.jpg"` , changed `/o-n` again to `/on` :)

Answer (score 1):

The method below just requires that you complete the capitalization of the words. You may look here for "batch capitalize words".

**EDIT**: I fixed a small bug and added the capitalize method.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define lists for teams and drivers
set teamList=Ferrari Lotus Mclaren
set driverList=Hamilton Schumacher Senna

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B *.jpg *.png') do (

   rem Initialize circuit
   set "circuit=%%a"
   set "circuit= !circuit:_= ! "

   rem Identify year
   for %%a in (!circuit!) do (
      if %%a gtr 1900 if %%a lss 2100 (
         set "year=%%a"
         set "circuit=!circuit: %%a = !"
      )
   )

   rem Identify team
   set "team="
   for %%a in (!circuit!) do (
      if "!teamList:%%a=!" neq "%teamList%" (
         set "team=%%a"
         set "circuit=!circuit: %%a = !"
      )
   )
   if defined team (
      call :Capitalize team
   ) else (
      echo Team not defined in list: "%%a"
      goto :EOF
   )

   rem Identify driver
   set "driver="
   for %%a in (!circuit!) do (
      if "!driverList:%%a=!" neq "%driverList%" (
         set "driver=%%a"
         set "circuit=!circuit: %%a = !"
      )
   )
   if defined driver (
      call :Capitalize driver
   ) else (
      echo Driver not defined in list: "%%a"
      goto :EOF
   )

   call :Capitalize circuit

   rem Check for duplicates
   set "newName=!year! - !circuit! - !team! - !driver!"
   set "number="
   if exist "!newName!" (
      for /L %%n in (2,1,20) do if not defined number (
         if not exist "!newName! (%%n)" set "number= (%%n)"
      )
   )

   ECHO ren "%%a" "!newName!!number!"

)
goto :EOF


:Capitalize var

set "var="
for %%a in (!%1!) do (
   set "name=%%a"
   set "char=!name:~0,1!"
   for %%b in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
      set "char=!char:%%b=%%b!"
   )
   set "var=!var! !char!!name:~1!"
)
set "%1=%var:~1%"
exit /B
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try to check it. I will have to put the directory in the code as well. Right? Also, I think I can add the "delims=_" and make it work for underscores as well.

Comment: I just modified the code so it can also manage the underscores in the names. Copy it again...

Comment: I tried to use the first one but it did not work. I used it for .txt files as a test. I also added a circuitList. The filenames are the same

Comment: I apologize for the late reply. I fixed the bug and also completed the capitalize method. Note that you don't need to define the circuit list. If you may test the new version, look at _the time_ it tooks to complete the rename process...